# Google map api takes long time to load

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know my question is duplicate. But I need the exact answer. I have used the below js for google map api and perfectly works fine on my site but it takes so much time to load.On my site I am showing 100 markers on google map.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So can anyone tell me how can I improve the speed of my page.

thanks

Edit

```
function initialize() {
    var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(43.265305424381985, -88.81882460937499),
        markers,
        myMapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: secheltLoc,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,

        },

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    function initMarkers(map, markerData) {
        var newMarkers = [],
            marker;

        for (var i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markerData[i][1], markerData[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(pos);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                position: markerData[i].latLng,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: markerData[i].logo
            }),
                boxText = document.createElement("div");


            infoboxOptions = {
                content: boxText,
                disableAutoPan: true,
                maxWidth: 0,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
                zIndex: null,
                boxStyle: {
                    background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",

                    width: "450px"
                },
                closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
                closeBoxURL: "",
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
                isHidden: false,
                pane: "floatPane",
                enableEventPropagation: false
            };

            newMarkers.push(marker);
            //define the text and style for all infoboxes
            boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid #333; margin-top: 8px; background:white; color:#FFF; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; padding: 5px; border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px;height:100px; width:350px;";
            boxText.innerHTML = "<div class='mainDiv'><div class='forImg' style='float:left;margin:4px 0 0 3px;'><img src=" + markerData[i].image + " /></div><div style='float:right; width:220px; margin-top:5px; padding-left:10px;'><div class='titleImg'>" + markerData[i].title + "</div><div class='descriptionTool'>" + markerData[i].address + "</div></div></div>";
            //Define the infobox
            newMarkers[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);
            //Open box when page is loaded
            newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, marker);
            newMarkers[i].infobox.close();



            marker.set("myZIndex", marker.getZIndex());
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, this);
                    //marker.setIcon(icon1);
                    // styleIcon.set("color","#00ff00");
                    //map.panTo(markerData[i].latLng);
                }
                getHighestZIndex();
                this.setOptions({zIndex: highestZIndex + 1});
            })(marker, i));
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    newMarkers[i].infobox.close(map, this);
                    // marker.setIcon(icon2);
                    // map.panTo(markerData[i].latLng);
                }
                this.setOptions({zIndex: this.get("myZIndex")});
            })(marker, i));

        }

        return newMarkers;

    }

    markers = initMarkers(map, [

        { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(43.072919, -89.402315), title: "xyz", image: 'img.jpg', address: 'xcd'}
 { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(43.072919, -89.402315), title: "xyz", image: 'img.jpg', address: 'xcd'}
 { latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(43.072919, -89.402315), title: "xyz", image: 'img.jpg', address: 'xcd'}



    ]);

}
```

Comment: What does your code look like? How are you using the Google Maps Javascript API v3?  How are you loading your "100 markers"? Have you tried loading your markers with AJAX or are they all "hardcoded" into your PHP?

Comment: Not really, you should provide more details on how you creating the markers and provide the facts that led you to a conclusion that api takes long time to load.

Comment: sorry for mistake. I have updated my question. In my script markers are coming dynamically.

Comment: Your markers are "hardcoded" into the call to initMarkers (if you view source in a browser on your page you will see all the values listed out).  See [Mike Williams' description of the AJAX philosophy from his Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic11.htm), you are using what he describes as the Non-AJAX Philosophy.

Comment: @geocodezip i got your point but need to show all the markers (address) together after page load. Yes I also used ajax philosophy in search section but after first load i want to show all the markers. Hope you got my issue.thanks

Comment: You need to make the decision on what is the problem and what you are willing to do to fix it.  At this point, I don't have any way of "getting" your issue as I can't see the problem with the code you have posted (unless it is just the time to load the data for the 100 markers) and you aren't open to the possible fixes suggested.  Chrome has some good tools to see what is causing the delays on your page load.  I suggest you use them.

Comment: Linking to your actual map would be helpful. Then we could see the problems for ourselves.